# Problema ao clicar no botão, chamada ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Código:

```
<button id="click" class="button"></button>
    <div class="TableCSS">
        <table id="clickvent">
        </table>
    </div>
```

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#click").click(function(){
                if($("#clickvent").is(":visible")){
                        $("#clickvent").hide();
                    } else{
                        $("#clickvent").show();
                    }                   
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../Conteudo/click.html",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'html'
                })
                .done(function(retorno) {
                    $("#clickvent").html(retorno);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert("Algo está errado");
                });
            });
        });
```

Está chamando tudo certo porém quando clico no botão precisa clicar duas vezes para carregar o conteúdo da página `click.html`. Alguém sabe me indicar o erro ? E só ao apertar pela primeira vez acontece isso de ter que clicar duas vezes, para esconder o conteúdo está tudo normal só para carregar que acontece.

Comment: tem certeza que o problema é esse? Pq aparentemente você esconde/mostra a `#clickvent` quando clica.... comenta esse if `if($("#clickvent").is(":visible"))` e vê se resolve o problema...

Comment: Comentei mas ai não faz nada. Nem uma ação ao clicar o botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que clicar 2 vezes para aparecer porque quando a página é carregada a condição `if($("#clickvent").is(":visible"))` já dá verdadeiro então ele executa o `hide()` para somente no próximo click aparecer. Sugestão para solução é antes da execução do evento de `click` do botão adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
$("#clickvent").hide();
```

Outra solução seria adicionar no `CSS` o seguinte:

```
#clickvent {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: E quando eu tiver 2 botões, como faço para o conteúdo do segundo botão substituir o do primeiro que cliquei  ?

Comment: Você quer que o segundo botão substitua o conteúdo da tabela por outro?

Comment: Isso mesmo, teria como ?

Comment: Tem como sim @Kevin.F!

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta se souber como responda lá http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123363/segundo-bot%C3%A3o-substituindo-conte%C3%BAdo-do-primeiro/123392?noredirect=1#comment257141_123392]