# Segundo botão substituindo conteúdo do primeiro

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Com esse código abaixo quando clico no botão `mat` ele me trás os dados em uma table. Gostaria que ao clicar no botão `sp` substitua o conteúdo da tabela por outro.

***Código:***

```
<button id="mat" class="button"></button>
<button id="sp"></button>
    <table id="matriz">

    </table>
    <table id="saopaulo">

    </table>
```

```
    <script>      
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#matriz").hide();
                $("#mat").click(function(){
                    if($("#matriz").is(":visible")){
                            $("#matriz").hide();
                        } else{
                            $("#matriz").show();
                        }                   
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../Conteudo/Matriz.html",
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'html'
                    })
                    .done(function(retorno) {
                        $("#matriz").html(retorno);
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        alert("Algo está errado");
                    });
                });
            $("#saopaulo").hide();
                $("#sp").click(function(){
                    if($("#saopaulo").is(":visible")){
                            $("#saopaulo").hide();
                        } else{
                            $("#saopaulo").show();
                        }                   
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../Conteudo/saopaulo.html",
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'html'
                    })
                    .done(function(retorno) {
                        $("#saopaulo").html(retorno);
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        alert("Algo está errado");
                    });
                });
            });
     </script>
```

Comment: Qual erro apresenta?

Comment: Não apresenta erro, unica coisa que envés de substituir ele poe o conteúdo do outro botão embaixo do que já tem.

Comment: Nao entendi muito bem, ele ta criando outra tabela? Com qual id?

Comment: Ele faz em lugar separado porque você está dizendo pra fazer, se quer que ele substitua utilize a mesma tabela, agora se quer que ele alterne entre as tabelas, esconda uma e mostre a outra

Comment: Você só pode carregar 1 únivo evento `.html()` na sua página, para fazer isso mais de uma vez, tem que usar o evento `.delegate()`

Comment: @Kevin.F Você quer substituir o conteúdo de qual `table` quando clicar em `#sp`?

Comment: O conteúdo da table `matriz` pelo conteúdo da de `saopaulo`.

Comment: @Kevin.F desculpa a persistência mas é para ter certeza pegar o conteúdo da table `matriz` e passar para `table` `saopaulo`?

Comment: Não, tem 2 conteúdos o da table `matriz` quando clico nela cai o conteúdo dela, e quando clico na `sp` cai o conteúdo diferente que é a de `saopaulo` substituindo o da `matriz`. Vou editar la no código para ver melhor. Vê se deu para entender melhor, cada botão traz um conteúdo diferente só quero fazer o  da matriz sumir quando o de saopaulo apaerecer e vice e versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar dentro da `function` do `done` no ajax antes de atribuir o retorno no método `.html(...);` adicionar a seguinte linha:

No ajax de do click `sp`:

```
$("#matriz").empty(); //remove todos os nós filhos da table
```

Mesma coisa no ajax do click `mat`:

```
$("#saopaulo").empty(); //remove todos os nós filhos da table
```

Comment: @Kevin.F vê se isto resolve?

Comment: Show de bola, era isso valeu.

Answer (score 1):

O constragimento está aqui.:

```
$("#matriz").html(retorno);
```

e

```
$("#saopaulo").html(retorno);
```

Está a inserir o conteudo em sitios diferentes o por isso de aparecer as duas tabelas.
Poderá colocar apenas 1 id ou então alterar para.:

```
$("#matriz").html(retorno);
$("#saopaulo").html('');
```

e

```
$("#saopaulo").html(retorno);
$("#matriz").html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que se você fizer desta maneira irá resolver o seu problema, eu não testei, mas se não funcionar, tente colocar o delegate para cada um dos `eventClick`:

```
$(function() {
   $("#matriz, #saopaulo").hide();      
        function eventClick(elClick, elEvent, otherElement, url) {

         $(document).delegate(elClick, 'click', function() {
            if (!$(elEvent).is(":visible")) {
                $(elEvent).show();
            } else {
                $(elEvent).hide();
            }       
              $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'html'
                    })
                    .done(function(retorno) {
                        $(elEvent).html(retorno);
                        $(otherElement).html('');
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        alert("Algo está errado");
                    });
             });
       }
      eventClick('#matriz', '#mat', '#saopaulo', "../Conteudo/Matriz.html");
      eventClick('#saopaulo', '#sp', '#matriz',"../Conteudo/Matriz.html");
});
```

Comment: Não aconteceu nada nem um botão funcionou. E se eu quiser carregar outro conteúdo no botão `sp` que não seja o `Matriz.html` como faço ?

Comment: Pergunto: precisa fazer duas requisições ajax, ou pode ser uma só? Eu não vejo porque fazer duas? Além disso, é melhor trabalhar com dados em json, em vez de html.

Comment: Duas por que cada botão que clicar vira um conteúdo, tem como fazer com uma requisição isso ?

Comment: Olha, claro que tem... você teria que carregar todo o conteúdo, de ambas as tabelas não no click... mas direto no autoload do jquery... e no botão, vc coloca só para mostrar o conteúdo que vc quer mostrar.

Comment: O ideal é vc trabalhar os dados em JSON, e depois dar um loop na tabela... O processo é bem mais rápido.

Comment: Não sei mexer com JSON.

Comment: JSON é como array: `[{chave:valor1}, {chave:valor2}]`, no php seria: `$data['chave'] = array('valor1','valor2');`

Comment: Ok entendi, vou fazer um estudo em JSON.

Comment: [Aqui tem mais sobre esse assunto](http://www.json.org/).